# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ENU with italian menu

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssms

This is the problem:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDjCv.jpg)

I have Win10 in English, Sql Server 2016 (from MAPS) in English, SSMS in English but... SSMS menu is in Italian!!! I hate it!

I try:
1. reinstall SSMS English
2. reinstall SQL Server 2016 in English
3. change language from menu but I have the problem in image "Microsoft Visual Studio  is required but not installed" BUT IT IS INSTALLED!!!!

I'm desperate!

EDIT:
and if my Win10 WAS installed in Italian with language pack in English? May confused SSMS??

EDIT 2: I don't find the problem, I don't find solution so I format e reinstall ALL my PC... with new English ISO and now all it's ok!!

Comment: Why is the Italian version of VS installed and English version of SSMS? Maybe the issue is the Italian VS and not SSMS.

Comment: @JacobH I don't know! I have only English software on my PC :O
I reinstall Sql Server 2016 in English and it have installed VS in Italian... on Win10 in English :(

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

1.Open this file with (notepad++ or any other text editor)
**c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\tools\binn\managementstudio\ssms.pkgundef**
2.search for "international" and comment the line with "//" 
Something like this  **"//[$RootKey$\ToolsOptionsPages\Environment\International Settings]"**
3.Open SSMS and change international cofiguration to English.
4.Restart SSMS

Enjoy :)

Comment: have you tried changing the language this way in ssms                                              > Tools > Options... > Environment > International Settings > Language

Comment: Yes! And I have only "italian" or "like Microsoft Windows"...
And I can't use "Add language" for the error "Microsoft Visual Studio is required but not installed"...

Comment: Try this:

1.Unistiall SSMS

2.Unistiall **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) , (Isolated should shown without English but another language)**.

_because SSMS V17 is a pulign of VS2015 Shell, if you have a non-English VS2015 Shell, SSMS shold not shown with English_.

3.Re-Install SSMS-ENG.

I think this will do the job :)

Comment: Yes, I tried it this morning...
Uninstall SSMS, SQL SERVER 2016 (with VS2015) and reinstall all in English... no way... I'm confused...
I try again... I download SSMS here: 
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms
- Available Languages
- English

it is correct?

Comment: Yes! it's correct all u  r doing but have you tried to uninstall the **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)**

Comment: Yes it's first morning test :)